# Reverse Engineer a program working as a webservice, the future?

Tags: python, web-services, open-source, reverse

*First I want to clearify that I mean by reverse engineering something like "decompiling" and getting back the original source code or something similiar.*

Yesterday I read a question about someone who wanted to protect his python code from "getting stolen" in other words: he didn't like that someone can read his python code.
The interesting thing I read was that someone said that the only reliable way to "protect" his code from getting reverse engineered is by using a Webservice.

So I could actually only write some GUIs in Python, PHP, whatever and do the "very secret code" I want to protect via a Webservice. (Basically sending variables to the host and getting results back).

Is it really impossible to reverse engineer a Webservice (via code and without hacking into the Server)? Will this be the future of modern commercial applications? The cloud-hype is already here. So I wouldn't wonder.

I'm very sorry if this topic was already discussed, but I couldn't find any resources about this.

EDIT: The whole idea reminds me of AJAX. The code is executed on the server and the content is sent to the client and "prettified". The client himself doesnt see what php-code or other technology is behind.

Comment: @AI G thank you for correcting my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, this is awesome! I've never thought it this way, but you could create a program that crawls an api, and returns as an output a django/tastypie software that mimics everything the api does.

By calling the service, and reading what it says, you can parse it, and begin to see the relationships between objects inside the api. Having this, you can create the models, and tastypie takes it from this point.

The awesome thing about this, is that normal people (or at least not backend developers) could create an api just by describing what they want to be as an output. I've seen many android/iphone developers creating a bunch of static xml or json, so they can call their service, and start the frontend development. Well what if that was enough? Take some xml/json files as input, get a backend as an output.

Comment: that what I'm speaking about. you understand me :) the good thing: you can maintain the "secret code" very easy by just having a server running this webservice-code, the gui can actually be always the same or very rarly updated. the "bad" thing is: you client always needs an Internet connection. but the internet spreads fast.

Comment: well, to answer your question: No, I've never seen something like this. But yes, if you don't find any resources, I'd gladly collaborate with you on a github project. BTW: I'm fceruti on github too.

Comment: well I got many ideas. We could chat sometime :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

All they could do is treat your web service as a black box, query the WSDL for all the parameters it accepts and the data that it returns.

They could then submit different variables and see what different results are.  The "code" could not be seen or stolen (with proper security) but the inputs and outputs could be duplicated.

If you want to secure your "very secret code" a web service *is* a great way to protect the actual code.

-sb

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by reverse engineering: by repeatedly sending input and analyzing the output the behaviour of your code can still be seen. I wouldn't have your code but I can still see what the system does. This means I could build a similar system that does the same thing, given the same input.

It would be hard to catch exceptional cases (such as output that is different on one day of the year only) but the common behaviour can certainly be copied. It is similar to analyzing the protocol of an instant messaging client: you may not have the original code but you can still build a copy.

Comment: I only speak about reverse engineering by code. Not by output. I know that this is also possible. (a technique used for building for example a private game-server)